# Select and insert blobs as input streams using Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring-jdbc

Using a plain JdbcTemplate, I can do it like this

```
LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
InputStream inputStream= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "SELECT data FROM blob_table WHERE id = ?",
        new Object[]{id},
        (rs, rowNum) -> lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, 1)
);

jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO blob_table (id, data) VALUES (?, ?)", ps -> {
    ps.setString(1, id);
    ps.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream);
});
```

but how should I do it using a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
MapSqlParameterSource idParameter = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);
LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();
InputStream result = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
        "SELECT data FROM blob_table WHERE id = :id",
        idParameter,
        (rs, rowNum) -> lobHandler.getBlobAsBinaryStream(rs, 1)
);

MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("id", id);
parameters.addValue("data", inputStream);
jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO blob_table (id, data) VALUES (:id, :data)", parameters);
```